# Importing from a text file with extra quotes with Backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I exported all the models from a Backbone collection with `JSON.stringify(collection.toJSON())` and managed to save it in a text file.

I want to import it, to recreate the collection.

The thing is, if I copy the text content and paste in the console...

```
collection.add(<-- and paste the text here -->)
```

the collection is created and everything work fine, but if I get the file content (using the File API), it doesn't work.

After a long inspection I think that the problem is here:

`[{ ....... }]` works but `"[{ ..... }]"` don't work, I don't understand what the difference between them is. How can convert from`"[{ ..... }]"` to `[{ ....... }]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data seems to have somehow become double-encoded. At some point after you already have a JSON string, you run `JSON.stringify()` on it a second time. That's why you have extra quotes on the outside.

If you need to do it this way, you should try to call `JSON.parse()` on the file contents before passing them to `collection.add()`.

Comment: The first time is before exporting, and the second time i read the file and i tried to add it directly, tried to pass it to a DOM element then get it with `.val`, I always get the same problem